# How to do callback in kivymd toolbar from the screen manager?

Tags: kivy, toolbar, kivy-language, kivymd

I tried to change the screen when I press on the toolbar icon, but kivy says that str object is not callable. How can I fix that? (I understand, that the problem is in syntax, please help)

```
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivymd.app import MDApp

KV = '''
Screen:    
    MDToolbar:
        id: toolbar
        pos_hint: {"top": 1}
        elevation: 10
        title: "MDNavigationDrawer"
        left_action_items: [["menu", lambda x: nav_drawer.set_state("open")]]

    NavigationLayout:    
        x: toolbar.height    
        ScreenManager:
            id: screen_manager    
            Screen:
                name: "scr 1"                
                  
                MDLabel:
                    text: "Screen 1"
                    halign: "center"    
            Screen:
                name: "scr 2"                    
                MDToolbar:
                    id: toolbar
                    pos_hint: {"top": 1}
                    elevation: 10
                    title: "MDNavigationDrawer"
                    left_action_items: [["arrow-left", lambda x: screen_manager.current("scr 1")]]                    
                MDLabel:
                    text: "Screen 2"
                    halign: "center"    
        MDNavigationDrawer:
            id: nav_drawer
               
            screen_manager: screen_manager
            nav_drawer: nav_drawer
                           
            ScrollView:    
                MDList:            
                    OneLineListItem:
                        text: "Screen 1"
                        on_press:                                self.parent.parent.parent.nav_drawer.set_state("close")                                self.parent.parent.parent.screen_manager.current = "scr 1"            
                    OneLineListItem:
                        text: "Screen 2"
                        on_press:                                self.parent.parent.parent.nav_drawer.set_state("close")                                self.parent.parent.parent.screen_manager.current = "scr 2"               
                    '''       
class TestNavigationDrawer(MDApp):    
    def build(self):
        return Builder.load_string(KV)  
TestNavigationDrawer().run()
```

TypeError: 'str' object is not callable

Answer (score 2):

I've found working solution.
Maybe it will be helpful for someone:

/main.py

```
class App(MDApp):
    kv_file = 'main.kv'


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = App()
app.run()
```

/main.kv

```
<Scr2@Screen>
    name: 'scr2'

    MDBoxLayout:
        orientation: 'vertical'
    
        MDToolbar:
            title: 'MDToolbar'
            left_action_items: [['arrow-left', lambda _: setattr(root.manager, 'current', 'scr1')]]

        MDLabel:
            text: 'Content'
            halign: 'center'
```

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem is a space in `scr 1`, try `scr1` or `scr_1` instead

try this

```
left_action_items: [["arrow-left", lambda x: root.manager.change_screen("scr1")]]
```

and in your `main.py` add this function

```
def change_screen(self, screen):
    # the same as in .kv: app.root.current = screen
    self.current = screen
```

Comment: Unfortunately no, and my screen name has str value.  Screen:
                name: "scr 1"

Comment: Doesn't  work. The problem is always the same (((I have added whole code